# How to refer to all child objects with existing queries in self-referencing foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that represents an owner. There is a foreign key on this model to itself to represent a parent entity. There is another model called asset with a foreign key to owner. The purpose of the parent foreign key is to emulate a corporate structure, such that a parent “owns” an Asset whose foreign key is itself or a subsidiary:

```
Class Owner(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
                 “self”,
             )

Class Asset(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
                 Owner,
             )
```

Is there a way return all assets owned by a parent and all of its subsidiaries by simply referencing the parent (eg Asset.object.filter(owner=parent))? I know I can create a method to return a queryset of all subsidiaries of a parent, and then filter to all assets in that owner queryset, but I am hoping to avoid a large refactor given the existing code base doesn’t have the concept of a parent owner.

My first thought is a custom manager, but I don’t think that will change the behavior of existing queries that are all off the default manager. Can I overload filter on this model? If I need to rethink design that is fine, but I think this approach is cleaner and captures the behavior we want. Thank you!

Comment: The Owner.parent relationship could be nested extremely deep, do you want all assets where the owner is any one of the nested children of the parent no matter how deep the nesting is?

Comment: That’s correct. In practice, I don’t see there being more than 6-7 layers.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL with the postgis extension

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not a satisfactory or complete answer but I have a raw postgres query that returns all children for a parent in a single query. It uses a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_all_children(self):
        return Owner.objects.raw(f"""
            with recursive t(id, parent_id) as
            (
                select id, parent_id
                from app_owner where id={self.id}
                union all
                select b.id, b.parent_id
                from app_owner b
                join t on b.parent_id=t.id
            )
            select * from t
        """)
```

This can be used to filter assets too

```
Asset.objects.filter(owner__in=Owner.objects.get(id=1).get_all_children())
```

Comment: It is to get 1 objects children. How to get List of recursive objects with one query?