# Django: how do you prefetch recursive fields?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
    required_items = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

Since it's a M2M relation, I can't use `select_related` to optimise my query, so I have to use `prefetch_related`. But I don't undertstand why I can't chose the depth of recursion, like I would with `select_related` and the `depth` parameter.

For example, to select 3 levels of recursion, I would expect some syntax like this to work (it doesn't):
`Item.objects.prefetch_related("required_items", depth=3).`

But instead, what I'm currently doing and is obviously awful is: `Item.objects.prefetch_related("required_items__required_items__required_items")`

I think I don't get it at some point...

**EDIT**

Based on Iain Shelvington idea, I tried to clean things up by making a custom Manager mixin:

```
class RecursiveAutoPrefetchManagerMixin:
    """ Manager mixin to allow a model with a recursive field to be automatically 
        prefetched at a given depth.
    """
    depth: int
    lookup_field: str

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.depth or not self.lookup_field:
            raise NotImplementedError("Mixin attribute is missing")
        lookup = '__'.join(repeat(self.lookup_field,self.depth))
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(lookup)
```

Then I use it like this in my model:

```
class ItemManager(RecursiveAutoPrefetchManagerMixin, models.Manager):
    depth = 3
    lookup_field = "required_items"

class Item(models.Model):
    objects = ItemManager()

    # ...
```

Comment: Could do something with [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) - `'__'.join(repeat('required_items', 3))`? Not sure it's cleaner though. Maybe something else - `'__'.join(['required_items'] * 3)`?

Comment: Yes but the point is not just to clean the syntax, but get it right at a conceptual level. I guess there is a reason why it's not possible to add a depth argument. And what if I have no idea of the tree depth in my database, and I want to optimise my query anyway?

Comment: It may not help you but it is possible to create recursive queries that will select all children for self referencing FKs, here's an example for postgres https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959133/548562. Django has to run a query for every level of prefetch, Django has no idea what depth to run the prefetch at before actually running the query so infinite depth is not feasible, it's a catch 22 problem