# How to effectively count multiple nested children in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following data model (the database backend is PostGres):

```
class User(models.Model):
...
teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', blank=True, related_name='all_users')
...
```

```
class Team(models.Model):
...
parent_team = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child_teams')
...
```

So a `User` can belong to multiple `Team`s, and the `Team`s can be nested in each other to varying degrees of depth.

I'd like to count all `User`s within a given team and all its children, including nested children (but exclude duplicates). Right now, I am doing it recursively, which doesn't seem like the most efficient way to go. Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: You can create a recursive query using raw SQL that returns all nested children using something like my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959133/548562